# Adapter class of Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, interface

I am a beginner in Java. I am learning Selenium as well and had a curiosity. Does WebDriver interface of Selenium has an adapter class of itself? What if I want to implement WebDriver in one of my own class in a project? Do I really need to override every single abstract methods or is there an adapter class to facilitate for utilizing only the methods I need and define them as well (but not all)?

Comment: Check out EventFiringWebDriver - https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html.

Comment: Can you share your code trials please?